# Error [parser.cc:488] Moveit package launch file

Tags: ros, moveit

**After creating moveit configuration when I run package I got this error
Can anyone help ?** **Moveit file is created by URDF file.**

I think it has problem with URDF version,plugin,element
and also a virtual link was defined while moveit configuration

```
Error [parser.cc:488] parse as old deprecated model file failed.
Error Code 4 Msg: Required attribute[filename] in element[plugin] is not specified in SDF.
Error Code 8 Msg: Error reading element <plugin>
Error Code 8 Msg: Error reading element <model>
Error Code 8 Msg: Error reading element <sdf>
^C[rviz_jainvrushab5_Aspire_A515_57G_7088_5365637007365382675-10] killing on exit
[move_group-9] killing on exit
[virtual_joint_broadcaster_0-8] killing on exit
[robot_state_publisher-7] killing on exit
[gazebo_controller_spawner-6] killing on exit
[controller_spawner-5] killing on exit
[spawn_gazebo_model-4] killing on exit
[gazebo_gui-3] killing on exit
[gazebo-2] killing on exit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 523, in call
    responses = transport.receive_once()
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_base.py", line 744, in receive_once
    self.stat_bytes += recv_buff(sock, b, p.buff_size)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_base.py", line 111, in recv_buff
    raise TransportTerminated("unable to receive data from sender, check sender's logs for details")
rospy.exceptions.TransportTerminated: unable to receive data from sender, check sender's logs for details

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/gazebo_ros/spawn_model", line 239, in <module>
    exit_code = sm.run()
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/gazebo_ros/spawn_model", line 183, in run
    success = gazebo_interface.spawn_urdf_model_client(self.args.model, model_xml, self.args.robot_namespace,
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/gazebo_ros/gazebo_interface.py", line 32, in spawn_urdf_model_client
    resp = spawn_urdf_model(model_name, model_xml, robot_namespace, initial_pose, reference_frame)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 442, in __call__
    return self.call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 531, in call
    raise rospy.exceptions.ROSInterruptException("node shutdown interrupted service call")
rospy.exceptions.ROSInterruptException: node shutdown interrupted service call
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/controller_manager/spawner", line 219, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__': main()
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/controller_manager/spawner", line 123, in main
    rospy.sleep(0.2)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rospy/timer.py", line 165, in sleep
    raise rospy.exceptions.ROSInterruptException("ROS shutdown request")
rospy.exceptions.ROSInterruptException: ROS shutdown request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/controller_manager/spawner", line 219, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__': main()
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/controller_manager/spawner", line 123, in main
    rospy.sleep(0.2)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rospy/timer.py", line 165, in sleep
    raise rospy.exceptions.ROSInterruptException("ROS shutdown request"  rospy.exceptions.ROSInterruptException: ROS shutdown request
```